# python unzip files and provide update to wxPython status bar

Tags: python, progress, statusbar, progressdialog, zip

I have several large zip file that contain a dir structure that I must maintain.  Currently to unzip them I am using

```
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(self.fileName)        
    zip.extractall(self.destination)
    zip.close()
```

The problem is that these process can take upwards of 3-5 minutes and I have no feedback that they are still working.  What I would like to do is output the name of the file currently being unziped to the status bar of my gui.  What I have in mind is something like

```
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(self.fileName)
    zipNameList = zipfile.namelist(self.fileName)
    for item in zipNameList:
        self.SetStatusText("Unzipping" + str(item))
        zip.extract(item)
    zip.close()
```

The problem with this is that it does not create the correct dir structure.  I am not sure that this is even the best way to go about it.

I was also looking into using wx.progressdialog but could not come up with a way to have it show progress of the zip.extractall(filename).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to an acceptable solution - Though I think I would prefer it thread it eventually.

```
def unzipItem(self, fileName, destination)
    print "--unzipItem--"
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName)
    nameList = zip.namelist()

    #get the amount of files in the file to properly size the progress bar
    fileCount = 0
    for item in nameList:
        fileCount += 1

    #Built progress dialog
    dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Unziping files",
                           "An informative message",
                           fileCount,
                           parent = self,
                           )

    keepGoing = True
    count = 0

    for item in nameList:
        count += 1
        dir,file = os.path.split(item)
        print "unzip " + file

        #update status bar
        self.SetStatusText("Unziping " + str(item))
        #update progress dialog
        (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count, file)
        zip.extract(item,destination)

    zip.close()
```

Comment: To get the amount of files you can use `len(nameList)` rather than that first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`infolist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) instead of `namelist`. From the docs:

> The objects are in the same order as their entries in the actual ZIP
>   file on disk if an existing archive was opened.

Also, consider this note:

> The open(), read() and extract() methods can take a filename or a ZipInfo object. You will appreciate this when trying to read a ZIP file that contains members with duplicate names.

So you can write something like this:

```py
with ZipFile(zip_file_name) as myzipfile:
    members = myzipfile.infolist()
        for i, member in enumerate(members):
            myzipfile.extract(member, destination_path)
            self.SetStatusText("Unziping " + str(i))
            self.mysignal.emit(i) # use this to update inside a thread
```

You can put this on a thread and then update through a signal, and the `SetStatusText` method should be called inside the corresponding slot.